# Retrieve a specific field from the result of Get-ItemProperty in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I've the below powershell script:

```
$registrypath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard"
$Name = "EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity"
$ExpectedValue = "1"
$value = Get-ItemProperty -Path $registrypath -Name $Name

Write-Host($value)
```

Its output is:

```
    @{EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity=1; PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard; PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control; PSChildName=DeviceGuard; PSDrive=HKLM; 
PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry}
```

I want to get the value of EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity field in it to a variable in my powershell script.

Like `$SpecificFieldValue = $value.get(EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity);`

How do i do it in powershell ?

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ItemProperty` offers you an `PSCustomObject` as response.

This means you can directly get the value of the property like this:

```
$value.EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity
```

or directly save the Value in the `Get-ItemProperty`-call like this:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $registrypath -Name $Name).EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity
```

or like this

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $registrypath -Name $Name | Select-Object -Expandproperty EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity
```

---

I think the problem is, that you expect the response to be an `hashtable` instead of an `PSCustomObject`.

You can get informations about the ObjectType of an Response by just adding `()` around a call and calling the `getType()` methode:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $registrypath -Name $Name).GetType()
```